# why return negative values

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avaudioplayer

I want to display the list of audio files inside a directory and their duration, so to get the  duration I use:

```
AVAudioPlayer * sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:nil];

NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", sound.duration]);

cell.detailTextLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Duration: %.2f sec", sound.duration];
```

But sometimes `sound.duration` return a negative value. I would like to know why, and how to solve it.

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

```
AudioFileID                     audioFile;
CFDictionaryRef piDict = nil;
UInt32 piDataSize   = sizeof( piDict );

if (noErr != AudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath], 0x01, kAudioFileCAFType, &audioFile))
{
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithString:filePath], @"FilePath", @"Unknown",@"Title",@"Unknown",@"Album",@"Unknown",@"Artist",@"0", @"Duration", nil];
}
if( noErr != AudioFileGetProperty( audioFile, kAudioFilePropertyInfoDictionary, &piDataSize, &piDict ))
{
    AudioFileClose(audioFile);
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithString:filePath], @"FilePath", @"Unknown",@"Title",@"Unknown",@"Album",@"Unknown",@"Artist",@"0", @"Duration", nil];
}

AudioFileClose(audioFile);

if(piDict)
{
    NSString * duration = @"0";
    CFStringRef      durationString = nil;
    if ( piDict && CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent(piDict, CFSTR(kAFInfoDictionary_ApproximateDurationInSeconds), (const void **) &durationString))
    {
        duration = (NSString*)durationString;
        duration = [duration stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
    }
    if (duration)
        [songInfomationDictionary setObject:duration forKey:@"Duration"];


    CFRelease(piDict);
    //get duration as string
}   
return nil;
```

Comment: Its nice to add a bit of explanation as well as a wall of code

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you..
in your code you are printing in nslog without assign and wrong format so its give in minus. so check it once.

```
AVAudioPlayer * sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/Users/apple/Desktop/LabelTextDemo/LabelTextDemo/song2.caf"] error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", sound.duration]);
```

Comment: the problem in this line cell.detailTextLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Duration: %.2f sec", sound.duration];

Comment: lblLabel2.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", sound.duration]; i m doing like this and its working